# actual machine code to execute what Win APIs do stays in OS kernel memory space or compiled together as part of the app?

Tags: winapi, operating-system

If this question deals with too basic a matter, please forgive me.

As a somewhat-close-to-beginner-level programmer, I really wonder about this--whether the underlying code of every win API function is compiled altogether at the time of writing an app, or whether the machine code for executing win APIs stays in the memory as part of the OS since the pc is booted up, and only the app uses them?

All the APIs for an OS are used by many apps by means of function call. So I thought that rather than making every individual app include the API machine code on their own, apps just contain the header or signature to call the APIs and the API machine code addresses are mapped when launching the app.

I am sorry that I failed to make this question succinct due to my poor English. I really would like to get your insights. Thank you.

Comment: Most of the API is implemented via shared DLLs which are mapped into your processes address space.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Thank you for your enlightening. Then does it encompass the APIs invoked from C, C++, which are not part of dotnet world? I know C, but only used C# to actually use a lot of APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation for (most) API calls is provided by the system by way of compiled modules ([Portable Executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) images). Application code only contains enough information so that the system can identify and load the required modules, and resolve the respective imports.

As an example consider the following code that shows a message box, waits for it to close, and then exits the program:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    ::MessageBoxW(nullptr, L"Foo", L"Bar", MB_OK);
}
```

Given the function signature (declared in *WinUser.h*, which gets pulled in from *Windows.h*) the compiler can *almost* generate a `call` instruction. It knows the number of arguments, their expected types, and the order and location the callee expects them in. What's missing is the actual target address inside *user32.dll*, that's only known after a process was fully initialized, and had the *user32.dll* module mapped into its address space.

Clearly, the compiler cannot postpone code generation until after load time. It needs to generate a `call` instruction *now*. Since we know that [*"all problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirection) that's what the compiler does, too: Instead of emitting a direct call instruction it generates an indirect call. The difference is that, while a direct call immediately needs to provide the target address, an indirect call can specify the address at which the target address is stored.

In x86 assembly, instead of having to say

```
    call _MessageBoxW@16   ; uh-oh, not yet known
```

the compiler can conveniently delegate the call to the [Import Address Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#import-address-table) (IAT):

```
    call dword ptr [__imp__MessageBoxW@16]
```

Disaster averted, we've bought us just enough time to fix things up before the code actually executes.

Once a process object is created the system hands over control to its primary thread to finish initialization. Part of that initialization is loading dependencies (such as *user32.dll* here). Once that has completed, the system finally knows the load address (and ultimately the address of imported symbols, such as `_MessageBoxW@16`), and can overwrite the IAT entry at address `__imp__MessageBoxW@16` with the imported function address.

And that is approximately how the system provides implementations for system services without requiring client applications to know where (physically) they will find them.

I'm saying *"approximately"* because things are somewhat more involved in reality. If that is something you'll want to learn about, I'll leave it up to Raymond Chen. He has published a [series](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060727-04/?p=30333) of blog entries covering this topic in far more detail:

- [How were DLL functions exported in 16-bit Windows?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060714-16/?p=30513)
- [How were DLL functions imported in 16-bit Windows?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060717-13/?p=30503)
- [How are DLL functions exported in 32-bit Windows?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060718-32/?p=30483)
- [Exported functions that are really forwarders](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060719-24/?p=30473)
- [Rethinking the way DLL exports are resolved for 32-bit Windows](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060720-20/?p=30453)
- [Calling an imported function, the naive way](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060721-06/?p=30433)
- [How a less naive compiler calls an imported function](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060724-00/?p=30403)
- [Issues related to forcing a stub to be created for an imported function](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060725-00/?p=30383)
- [What happens when you get dllimport wrong?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060726-00/?p=30363)
- [Names in the import library are decorated for a reason](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060727-00/?p=30343)
- [Why can't I GetProcAddress a function I dllexport'ed?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040112-00/?p=41083)

Comment: Extremely very much, thank you, sir. What an elaborate, precious answer this is! You really enlightened me so clearly. Your answer would be very helpful for many people. I will also reference the links you provided. I wish you a lovely day.